# What happens if return EXIT_FAILURE without using fclose()?

Tags: c, file, io, fclose

Suppose I use fopen and deem the file format to be invalid for my program or the pointer is NULL. What consequences are there to simply returning EXIT_FAILURE when I reach that situtation, without using fclose?

Comment: Returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`. Some of the things that does is to flush streams with unwritten data, close all streams, and remove all files created with `tmpfile`.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any consequences of simply returning EXIT_FAILURE when the file pointer is NULL or you code the file format to be invalid. It would be a simple exit of the program with EXIT_FAILURE return value. Although you can make use of `atexit()` function to clean up resources on exit when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `EXIT_FAILURE` is a macro defined in `stdlib.h` library which expands to `1`. In the other hand, the macro `EXIT_SUCCESS` constant expands to `0`. In our general convention, returning `0` to the main function states that the code did run successfully, otherwise incorrectly exited.

Also, to flush streams and undo the things, `atexit()` will do the work.

Notice that we'll be using `x` globally since the function which are going to be passed as argument in `atexit()` must not pass anything in it. The function signature of `atexit()` according to [C++ Reference (using C declaration)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) is as follows:

```
int atexit (void (*func)(void));
```

Let's assume the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// will be used for atexit()
void exit_stuffs(void);

// to use return code
int x;

int main(void) {
    int a = 4;

    x = (a < 5) ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;

    atexit(&exit_stuffs);
    
    return x;
}

void exit_stuffs(void) {
    printf("The return code was: %d\n", x);
}
```

This will assign `EXIT_FAILURE` to `x` and then return `x`. On the exit of the program, an example of using `atexit()` is also given.

Answer (score 0):

> What consequences are there to simply returning EXIT_FAILURE when I reach that situtation, without using fclose?

None, with an exception: if you were writing to the file then some data will be lost. That's pretty much it, and it doesn't matter what you return - `EXIT_FAILURE` is by no means special on typical operating systems.